# Window not redirected to correct URL passed from Json return

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-2

```
function GetOpenUrl(transactionId, legacyIndication)
    {
        var json = {
            id : transactionId,
            legacyIndication : legacyIndication
        };
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%= Url.Action("OpenSavedIndication", "Indications") %>",
            data: json,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                //window.location = data;
            }
        });
    }
```

So when I perform that alert, I get the correct URL:

> "/Extranet/mvc/Indications.cfc/Economics/02559e2e-d48e-4623-b877-69f36aa8b011"

However, if I let it run, I get an error page that says:

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL:
>   /Extranet/mvc/Indications.cfc/"/Extranet/mvc/Indications.cfc/Economics/02559e2e-d48e-4623-b877-69f36aa8b011"/Extranet/mvc/Indications.cfc/"/Extranet/mvc/Indications.cfc/Economics/02559e2e-d48e-4623-b877-69f36aa8b011"

what is happening?

Edit:

Controller action return code:

```
return Json(Url.Action("Economics", new { id = indicationBase.ID }));
```

Comment: Are you returning a relative URL? Should it be relative? Can you show your controller action?

Comment: added the return line from the action above. thanks

Comment: There seem to be an additional `"` in the requested url. Where does it come from? I tested the code and it worked fine so I guess there's something else going on (in some part of the code that you haven't shown).

Comment: It's weird how if I alert the response data, it shows me the correct URL, however, when I try re-directing to it, it all messes up.

Comment: How about `window.location.href = data;`? Does it make any difference?

Comment: Try returning a hardcoded **absolute** url from your controller action to see if it makes any difference: `return Json("http://example.com/Extranet/mvc/Indications.cfc/Economics/02559e2e-d48e-4623-b877-69f36aa8b011");`

Comment: If I do that I get this error : A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

Comment: Hmm, weird. Where is this exception thrown? From the action you are redirecting to? Can you try reproducing this in a new MVC application?

Comment: Exception doesn't get thrown until I try and perform the re-direct.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is, the URL i can alert is "/Extranet/mvc/Indications.cfc/Economics/e6f1113d-79f8-4026-8e9b-3036b088c2bc", but shouldn't it say the host in front of that?

Comment: The `Url.Action` method returns relative urls.

Comment: Hmm, okay. then i have no idea why it's not redirecting correctly..lol

Comment: If I put this: window.location.href = "<%=Url.Action("Economics", "Indications") %>"; instead it works, but obviously doesn't go to the right place, b/c I leave the Id out

Comment: Also, if I direct right to it: window.location.href = "http://localhost/Extranet/mvc/Indications.cfc/Economics/3b3f27a8-ff58-4bd9-bf24-d42eecfc64bc"; that works as well....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the controller action to just return the Id, and now I redirect like this:

```
var idData = JSON.parse(data);
window.location = "Economics/" + idData.id;
```

Seems to work fine.